# Создание правильных связей в моделях Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin, django-orm

Передо мной стоит задача настроить модели в приложении таким образом, чтобы у меня была главная модель Spectrum, которая состоит из трех дополнительных моделей SpectrumMeasurement,  SpectrumField, SpectrumPeak.

Пример кода:

```
class Spectrum(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="author")
    measurements = models.ForeignKey('SpectrumMeasurement', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="measurements", null=True)
    peaks = models.ForeignKey('SpectrumPeak', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="peaks", null=True)
    fields = models.ForeignKey('SpectrumField', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="fields", null=True)


class SpectrumMeasurement(models.Model):
    source = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    level = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ionization = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    polarity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


class SpectrumField(models.Model):
    meta_data = models.JSONField(default=None, null=True)


class SpectrumPeak(models.Model):
    peaks_data = models.JSONField(default=None)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, default="")
```

Я создаю пустую модель Spectrum

```
Spectrum.objects.create()
```

Далее создаю 3 модели

```
SpectrumField.objects.create(id=id)
SpectrumMeasurement.objects.create(id=id)
SpectrumPeak.objects.create(id=id)
```

После чего добавляю нужные мне данные в эти 3 модели

```
SpectrumPeak.objects.create(peaks_data=peaks_values)

или

peaks = SpectrumPeak.objects.filter(id=id)
peaks.peaks_data = peaks_data
peaks.save()
```

В конце я обновляю основную модель Spectrum:

```
Spectrum.objects.filter(id=id).update(name=name, author=request.user, measurements=id, peaks=id, fields=id)
```

В результате всех этих действия я вижу в админке 4 модели, которые я прописал в admin.py

```
class SpectrumFieldAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class SpectrumMeasurementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class SpectrumPeakAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class SpectrumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(SpectrumField, SpectrumFieldAdmin)
admin.site.register(SpectrumMeasurement, SpectrumMeasurementAdmin)
admin.site.register(SpectrumPeak, SpectrumPeakAdmin)
admin.site.register(Spectrum, SpectrumAdmin)
```

В админке отображаются эти модели, в модели Spectrums я вижу все нужные мне поля: name, author, create_date, measurements, peaks, fields. В этих полях прописаны объекты моделей из других таблиц (например, SpectrumMeasurement Object 1)

Когда я удаляю основной объект из Spectrums, то удаляется у меня только сам объект Spectrum Object, но не удаляются связанные объекты из других таблиц.
Можно сделать, чтобы ForeigKey были прописаны не в основном классе Spectrum, а в 3-х других, тогда я смогу удалить все связанные объекты при удалении объекта спектра, но я не буду видеть в админке все объекты, связанные с объектом спектра.
Как правильно настроить связи, чтобы можно было через админку видеть какие объекты из таблиц связаны с основным объектом Spectrum и при этом удалять сразу все связанные таблицы одним нажатием при удалении объекта спектра? И возможно ли получать и обновлять значения в связанных таблицах через основную модель Spectrum?

[image: Так выглядит админка сейчас]

[image: удаление объекта Spectrum]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут нужно поменять поход:

```
class Spectrum(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
                               related_name="author")


class SpectrumMeasurement(models.Model):
    source = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    level = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ionization = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    polarity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    spectrum_instanse = models.ForeignKey('Spectrum', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                          related_name='measurement')


class SpectrumField(models.Model):
    meta_data = models.JSONField(default=None, null=True)
    spectrum_instanse = models.ForeignKey('Spectrum', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                          related_name='field')


class SpectrumPeak(models.Model):
    peaks_data = models.JSONField(default=None)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, default="")
    spectrum_instanse = models.ForeignKey('Spectrum', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                          related_name='peak')
```

Comment: Да, такой вариант можно сделать, я пробовал, но тогда в админке, если я открою объект Spectrum, то не увижу в нем поля, которые содержат данные из 3-х других таблиц. Если это нормальная практика, то я готов с этим смириться) Но вдруг есть варианты.

Comment: связанные данные можно выводить в шаблоне по related_name: spectrum_object.peak

Comment: А можно пример по одной из таблиц, как вывести для спектра данные по SpectrumPeak?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey посмотрите примеры использования related_name

Comment: и да, важно понимать что отношение у нас многие к одному поэтому spectrum_object.peak.all(). Если результаты измерений спектра могут быть только одни то логичней использовать OneToOneField

Comment: Ты можешь помочь с настройкой этого всего? Договоримся!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145256/discussion-between-rpe4ka722-and--).